# request.meta vs class attributes scrapy

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

In order to handle data between callbacks in scrapy, it is possible to define class attributes:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.my_var = 1
```

and use:

```
self.my_var
```

instead of:

```
request.meta['my_var'] = 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`request.meta`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#passing-additional-data-to-callback-functions) is the perfect and reliable way to pass meta information *tied to a specific request*. For example, if you parse basic product information from the product list page and want to pass along this information to the product details page callback - `request.meta` is the perfect solution. [`meta` also has a number of special keys](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#request-meta-special-keys) that allow to control the behavior of a specific request.